# Array is not working while reading JSON file in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

When iterating array in JavaScript , it reads first field but while taking second field automatically index changed from 0 to 1. Please find below for reference.

Here the first field is getting read successfully, even when I comment first line of obj that time testing group also reads successfully. but I want to iterate both. and when I try to iterate both, index gets changes and error comes.

Find below the loop I am using.

```js
for (var k=0;k<obj.length;k++) { 
  console.log(obj[0]); 
  $('#resText').val(result[obj[k]['value'].replace('',k)]); 
  var a = "result"+obj[k]['value'].replace('',k); 
  $('#resText').val(eval(a)); 
  alert(eval(a));
}
```

Comment: plese find below loop i am using.

for (var k=0;k<obj.length;k++)
{
            console.log(obj[0]);
   $('#resText').val(result[obj[k]['value'].replace('*',k)]);
   var a = "result"+obj[k]['value'].replace('*',k);
   $('#resText').val(eval(a));
   alert(eval(a));
}

Comment: Click the `edit` link below your question to update..